# Feather install error with pip3

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, feather

Hey everyone while I am trying to `pip3 install feather` this error popup on the screen.

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mijuoz_z/feather/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mijuoz_z/feather/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
        return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mijuoz_z/feather/distribute_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download
        _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mijuoz_z/feather/distribute_setup.py", line 99, in _build_egg
        _extractall(tar)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-mijuoz_z/feather/distribute_setup.py", line 467, in _extractall
        self.chown(tarinfo, dirpath)
    TypeError: chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mijuoz_z/feather/
```

Comment: Try `pip install feather-format`.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be this big bad error shown underneath it.

```
TypeError: chown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'numeric_owner'
```

What are your arguments to `chown()` function?